# Best image file format for book pages

Tags: image, file, jpeg

I wanted to scan Book pages and combine the images to an pdf "ebook" (just for me), but the file sizes get really huge. Even .jpg resulted in an pdf file with 60mb+ in size.

Do you have any idea how I can compress it any further? I.e. which file format I could choose for this specific purpose? (The book contains pictures and written text.)

Thank you for your help.

I tried to save it as .jpg and other file formats like .png, but didnt get small enough for the file to be easy handled, without loosing to much resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Images are expensive things.

Ignoring compression you’re looking at 3bytes per pixel of data.

If you want to keep images you could reduce this by turning your images into greyscale. That reduces it to 1byte per pixel (again ignoring compression).

Or you could turn it into black and white. Which would be 1 but per pixel.

Or, alternatively, you could use OCR to translate your image into actual text which is a much more efficient way of storing books.